# Error: Series is ambiguous | Function with multiple arguments | DataFrame

Tags: python, function, dataframe, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

I want to have a simple function that would categorize numeric values from existing column into a new column. For some reason when doing it with a function that has multiple arguments "*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*" is generated...

**DataFrame:**

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
df_=pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=["Nums"])
```

[image: dataframe output]

**Code that generate Error:**

```
n1=2
n2=4
def func(x,y,z):
 if (x>=y) & (x<=z):
    return('good')
 else:
    return('bad')
df_['Nums_Cat']=func(df_.Nums, n1, n2)
```

[image: error line]

Please note, that I'm trying to do this with a function approach as it will be applied to multiple columns with many different conditions passed.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case I'm trying to convert those numeric values that fall under this condition into string "good" and those that dont (else) into string "bad" So, that output should be 'bad, good, good, good' in a new column called Num_Cat.

Your nearly there. However Python's functions don't work the way you want. To do what you want you need to `map` each value from the result into either "good" or "bad".

```py
def func(x, y, z):
    values = (y <= x) & (x <= z)
    return values.map(lambda item: "good" if item else "bad")
```

Comment: That would make sense, however .any() and .all() don't seem to fit into my logic...
In this case I'm trying to convert those numeric values that fall under this condition into string "good" and those that dont (else) into string "bad"
So, that output should be 'bad, good, good, good' in a new column called Num_Cat. Using .all() or any() converts all of them into either 'good' or 'bad'

Comment: I was in a middle of writing and accidentally posted a comment

Comment: Ah right! I was just thinking that using lambda function somehow could be a solution... thank you